# Code keeps trying to open a pop-up window of an image - not my intention

Tags: html, css, popup

I have this code:

```
<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="portfolio-item">
        <a href="1.html" class="set-bg port-pic" data-setbg="img/portfolio/1.jpg"></a>
        <h2>We Are Okay</h2>
        <p>Book design</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

but every time I click on the link (`1.html`) it doesn't go to the page but keeps trying to open a pop-up image.

What am I doing wrong?

The CSS is not very helpful, as it seems to set only the transition, positioning and size:

```css
/*---------------------
 Portfolio section
----------------------*/
.portfolio-warp {
 padding: 0 60px;
}

.portfolio-item h2 {
 font-size: 24px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.portfolio-item p {
 font-size: 14px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.portfolio-item .port-pic {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 display: block;
 height: 280px;
 background: #333;
 background-position: center center;
 background-size: cover;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

.portfolio-item .port-pic:after {
 position: absolute;
 content: '';
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 0;
 background: #000;
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: 2;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.09, 0.68, 0.53) 0s;
 -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.09, 0.68, 0.53) 0s;
 transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.09, 0.68, 0.53) 0s;
}

.portfolio-item:hover .port-pic:after {
 opacity: 0.8;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you remove the `port-pic` class?

Comment: i guess its something to do with the data-attribute in you anchor. Try removing that.

Comment: As Sirence mentioned, try removing `port-pic`. If that doesn't work, try removing `data-setbg`. It sounds like some JS is parsing links and changing them. Do you use some JS library/plugins?

Comment: Sounds like you have JavaScript creating a LightBox effect.

Comment: When I remove port-pic it removes the image entirely.

Comment: Removing data-setb takes out the image, but keeps the hover effect on the image. So essentially I am seeing a black square.

Comment: you can go to chrome developer console and look for event listeners and stuff to figure out whats causing this. If hard to guess something from this code snippet.